# JAVA - writing chars to a file in one byte per char

Tags: java, char

I couldn't find any documentation about this...
I want to write to a file a bunch of char and make sure that the file's size is # of chars bytes.

does anyone know what class to use?

Comment: What encoding?  ASCII?  What happens when a `char` can't be represented?  UTF-8?  What happens when a `char` is two bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to write to a file a bunch of char and make sure that the file's size is # of chars bytes.

Okay - so you need to pick an *encoding* which only uses a single byte per character, such as ISO-8859-1. Create a `FileOutputStream`, wrap it in an `OutputStreamWriter` specifying the encoding, and you're away. However, you need to be aware that you're limiting the range of characters which can be represented in your file.

Comment: Jon, it also might be worth a mention that this will _only_ impact external storage.  Within the memory of a Java program, these one byte characters will still be packed into java "characters", which are two bytes long.  The only way I can imagine working around that oddity is to keep everything in byte arrays (and re-implement a lot of standard functionality).

Comment: @EdwinBuck: Probably, anyway - I did hear about one JRE implementation which used UTF-8 within java.lang.String... However, I suspect the OP is sufficiently new to Java that it *may* be best not to introduce too many different ideas at a time.

Comment: @JonSkeet  - when i write:                     OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("path/name_string2.txt"));
os.write('d');      and check the file size, it says 0 bytes.

Comment: @kakush Dont forget to close your writer/streams

Comment: @kakush: Firstly, you're not specifying a character encoding (which I explicitly said to do). Secondly, unless you flush or close the writer, you're going to see buffering effects.

Comment: @JonSkeet perhaps you are thinking of the Java class file format?  The embedded constants use a modified form of UTF-8, but I can't imagine how a JVM at runtime would be valid if the char didn't support a full 16 bits of values!  It would brake the language, and the interfaces into java.lang.String.

Comment: @EdwinBuck: No, I'm talking about the JVM itself. `char` has to be a UTF-16 code unit, but a `String` itself can be internally represented in other ways. It may mess with JNI, admittedly...

Comment: @kakush: Don't forget to close writers etc in `finally` statements, so you don't leak handles if any exceptions are thrown.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sounds like that JVM found a really good way to make `string.length()` an O(n) operation.  Might be a reason why it's not so popular.

Comment: @EdwinBuck: `length()` is easy - you just keep it in a separate field. `charAt()` is the tricky one. There are alternatives though - you could have an implementation which uses byte-per-character for strings which are entirely ASCII, and two bytes for anything else, for example. In many cases that could have massive memory implications... but obviously there are drawbacks too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a "Writer"

Writer do output chars

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html

OutputStream do output bytes

You may try to use an other encoding.
In that case you should supply an **CharSetEncoder** as this has an **onUnmappableCharacter** method

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#onUnmappableCharacter%28java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction%29

Comment: Don't use `FileWriter` - it uses the platform default encoding, which may or may not be fixed-width of 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

First figure out which kinds of `chars` you are going to be talking about.

In `C` a `char` is eight bits, even if you need two or more `char`s in sequence to represent one glyph, or in human-terms, one typed character.  It gets worse, there are also glyphs that represent two "typed" characters, like the conjoined `ff` and `ll` glyphs you often see in typesetting.

If you are talking about `C` `char`s, then by definition every file contains the same number of chars as chars.  If you are talking about any other meaning of the word character, then you need to make some choices.

Eight bit characters are guaranteed for the ASCII character set in UTF-8, which is by far the best character set to choose going forward, as it has explicit support in web protocols (thank you w3c!).  This means that as long as you verify that every `java` `char` in your string is less than 128 (integer value), you are going to get one `byte` per `char` with `UTF-8`.

`ISO-8859-1` is a character set which also uses only one `byte` per character.  The downside to `ISO-8859-1` is that it *tends* to *not* be the default character set of anything *other than* Microsoft systems.  Even within the Microsoft realm, `UTF-8` has been making a lot of headway.

The cost to convert between the two is not overly high, but the extensibility of the two differ dramatically.  Basically, if you are using `ISO-8859-1` and someone tells you that the next product must support language "X", then in some cases, you must first convert to a different character set and then add the language support.  With `UTF-8` such a need to convert to another character set prior to adding support is rare.  I mean very rare, like so rare that you should consider just using images because the language is likely dead, is likely of historical interest only, and is likely to have been documented as a dialect from a lesser tribe on an island where the primary language has full support.